# How to make an app compatible with iOS7 and above only?

Tags: ios, app-store, titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to ensure that your app update is only compatible with iOS7 and above? I have a completely rewritten app, using Titanium JS, and I am issuing it as an update to a previously released app. However I don't want to let iOS6 users update to this version.

How can I do that? Is there a way to do it via iTunes Connect? Or would I have to modify my apps settings/codebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in iTunes connect. You have to do it in the code. This is pretty simple, you just need to add the following settings to the tiapp.xml file.

```
<ios>
   <min-ios-ver>7.0</min-ios-ver>
</ios>
```

This will set the minimum iOS version to 7.0
Note that you can change the version number given to any version like 6.1, you want to build for.